# React Logic / Dependency issue: Call a 3rd party API, get a batch of 100+ JSON entities, and CRUD store every 20~ seconds

Tags: reactjs, json, crud, store, zustand

I'm looking to accomplish this in a low overhead way, but I'm also looking to learn what the best practice would be.

I have React / Zustand / Immer app, that calls a 3rd party API every 20~ seconds that returns JSON with 100~ entities in it.

Currently, what I'm doing is looping through the entities, and CRUDing them using a Zustand store: (I'm not using removeBus yet, so that code is rough)

```
export const useBussesStore = create<MetroState>((set) => ({
    busses: [
        {
            id: '-1',
            latitude: 38.627003,
            longitude: -90.199402,
            timestamp: '1649680408',
            label: "Welcome to our performance",
            dupes: 1
        },
    ],
    movement: 0,
    addBus: (payload: Bus) =>
        set(
            produce((draft) => {
                draft.busses.push(payload);
            })
        ),
    removeBus: (payload: string) =>
        set(
            produce((draft) => {
                const dramaIndex = draft.busses.findIndex((el: any) => el.id === payload);
                draft.busses.splice(dramaIndex, 1);
            })
        ),
    patchBus: (payload: Bus) =>
        set(
            produce((draft) => {
                let bus = draft.busses.find((el: Bus) => el.id === payload.id);
                bus.latitude = payload.latitude;
                bus.longitude = payload.longitude;
            })
        ),
}));
```

Doing 100 state updates in a row seems wrong to me and I've had this issue for months and google has not helped.

Do you have a more logical way to do this?

I also have a Redux version of this that just replaces the list of entities.  It performs well, but isn't as cool as handling each entity individually.  I've been considering using a realtime database, but if it comes to that, I might just use my Redux version and bury this project.

Comment: what solution did you come up with here? Also, usually, you wouldn't run thru a 100 and update each one.. why not just batch update?

Comment: @jamesemanon I shelved this.  If I'm setting state from a single api call, isn't that batched already? also, looked into this: https://maximorlov.com/parallel-tasks-with-pure-javascript/